# Generating Java classes from XSD schema

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I am trying to generate java classes from XSD schema http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust-1.3.xsd.

For this I am using `jaxb2-maven-plugin` with `xjc` to generate those glasses. But run into following errors

```
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd [87,40]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 87; columnNumber: 40; A class/interface with the same name "com.abccompany.wstrust.ReferenceType" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.

[ERROR] http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd [97,35]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd; lineNumber: 97; columnNumber: 35; (Relevant to above error) another "ReferenceType" is generated from here.

[ERROR] http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd [87,40]
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 87; columnNumber: 40; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.

[ERROR] http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd [97,35]
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd; lineNumber: 97; columnNumber: 35; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
[ERROR] http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd [152,58]
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 152; columnNumber: 58; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class
[ERROR] http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd [96,52]
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd; lineNumber: 96; columnNumber: 52; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
```

So I tried to use bindings to resolve the conflict, this way

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" >
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='ReferenceType']">
        <jxb:class name="AbstractReferenceType1" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

But I still get following errors

```
[ERROR] http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd [152,58]
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd; lineNumber: 152; columnNumber: 58; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class
[ERROR] http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd [96,52]
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd; lineNumber: 96; columnNumber: 52; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
```

Tried to add bindings for `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` schema, but it is not working. How do you accurately find out this line number and column number mentioned in the error? If I just copy the schema in notepad, that line number comes to non-relevant xml tag.

Have anyone tried to generate these classes?

Comment: Where did `com.abccompany.wstrust.ReferenceType` come from? Is it from your custom XSD, because I am not seeing it referenced anywhere in the XSD or its imports that you provided.

Comment: That's the package name(`com.abccompany.wstrust`) I provided in my `pom.xml`

Comment: If I just do `xjc sw-trust-1.3.xml` I get java files without any errors. Perhaps a different plugin? (Java 1.8)

Comment: @KarlNicholas - with no bindings? I am using Java 1.8

Comment: @KarlNicholas - Interesting, it worked for me too. If I don't use any flags, it is working. But when I was passing `-p` for package, it threw the error.

Comment: @KarlNicholas - Please add your response as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest by @KarlNicholas, I ran `xjc` without any other option and it generated the classes for me. Every time, I passed `-p` as an option, it would throw an error that i posted in question.